# heroku run rake db:migrate reverts migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I am running my app on heroku, using the heroku pg stack, and when I run db:migrate it reverts my previous migrations instead of moving forward.

`rake db:version` shows the current migration

```
Current version: 20160516172744
```

`rake db:migrate:status` shows all migrations as up

```
......(more above all up)
   up     20160512175053  Create spree roles permissions.spree admin roles and access
   up     20160512175054  Add editable is default and index on editable is default and name to spree roles.spree admin roles and access
   up     20160513135317  Add indexes for speed
   up     20160513140704  Add filter search params to spree product
   up     20160516172744  Add tsvector colums to spree products
```

But when I hit heroku run rake db:migrate this is the output:

```
Migrating to AddTsvectorColumsToSpreeProducts (20160516172744)
== 20160516172744 AddTsvectorColumsToSpreeProducts: reverting =================
-- execute("      DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS spree_products_tsv_trigger() CASCADE;\n")
   -> 0.0031s
-- remove_index(:spree_products, :tsv)
   -> 0.0058s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :tsv)
   -> 0.0025s
== 20160516172744 AddTsvectorColumsToSpreeProducts: reverted (0.0122s) ========

Migrating to AddFilterSearchParamsToSpreeProduct (20160513140704)
== 20160513140704 AddFilterSearchParamsToSpreeProduct: reverting ==============
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :designer_id)
   -> 0.0062s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :main_taxon_id)
   -> 0.0024s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :colour_id)
   -> 0.0025s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :size_id)
   -> 0.0045s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :condition_id)
   -> 0.0023s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :on_site)
   -> 0.0023s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :sgd_price)
   -> 0.0025s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :search_designer)
   -> 0.0022s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :search_category)
   -> 0.0021s
-- remove_column(:spree_products, :search_sku)
   -> 0.0022s
== 20160513140704 AddFilterSearchParamsToSpreeProduct: reverted (0.0341s) =====
.....(cont.)
```

Any ideas?

-Dan

Comment: By any chance, does your environment have the [`VERSION`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#running-migrations) environment variable set?

Comment: it does but to 'v3'

Comment: @RobertNubel I think that might have been it!   You sir are amazing!

Comment: Awesome, I'll transfer to an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake db:migrate` will, without any arguments, only migrate *up* to the latest version. If you ever see it migrate down, you most likely have the `VERSION` environment variable set to some value (see [the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#running-migrations) for explanation of how that variable works), and Rails is trying to migrate to that version.

In your case, per the comments, it looks like you'd set `VERSION=v3` in your environment. Rails is likely casting `v3` to `0` and trying to migrate *all* migrations down.

Comment: Wait wait wait... I just lost production data because a container had a `VERSION` env var set, `rake` decided to pick that up as an *argument* - though it's an incredibly common term and appeared nowhere on the command line - and then, though it's in `production` mode and the value of `VERSION` was not anywhere close to a legit migration version - Rails deleted data with no warning via dropping columns? I'm not even sure what to think of this.

Comment: @nrser agreed, it's a poor design decision that was left in to keep backwards compatibility. It's too late to help you now, but a fix to only allow valid migration versions was just merged this month: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30714

Comment: Wow... I mean, for as horrible as taking arguments from a source you have terrible visibility into and that can be mutated by all sorts of other stuff on the system is, that's `rake`'s thing and not really Rails' fault, but, for f's sake, I would expect Rails to say "hey, this is a production DB and I'm about to trash data, that cool?" **Especially** when it's doing so *because it couldn't make sense of an 'argument' that I may have not even provided*.